# R apply error: 'X' must have named dimnames

Tags: r, dataframe

The "apply" documentation mentions that "Where 'X' has named dimnames, it can be a character vector selecting dimension names."  I would like to use apply on a data.frame for only particular columns.  Can I use the dimnames feature to do this?

I realize I can subset() X to only include the columns of interest, but I want to understand "named dimnames" better.

Below is some sample code:

```
> x <-  data.frame(cbind(1,1:10))
> apply(x,2,sum)
X1 X2
10 55
> apply(x,c('X2'),sum)
Error in apply(x, c("X2"), sum) : 'X' must have named dimnames
> dimnames(x)
[[1]]
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X2"
> names(x)
[1] "X1" "X2"
> names(dimnames(x))
NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to use apply only on certain columns. This is *not* what named dimnames would accomplish. The apply function on a matrix or data.frame always applies to *all* the rows or *all* the columns. The named dimnames allows you to choose to use rows or columns by name instead of the "normal" `1` and `2`:

```
m <- matrix(1:12,4, dimnames=list(foo=letters[1:4], bar=LETTERS[1:3]))
apply(m, "bar", sum)  # Use "bar" instead of 2 to refer to the columns
```

However if you have the column names you'd like to apply to, you could do it by first selecting only those columns:

```
n <- c("A","C")
apply(m[,n], 2, sum)
# A  C 
#10 42
```

Named dimnames is a side-effect of that dimnames are stored as a list in the "dimnames" attribute in a `matrix` or `array`. Each component of the list corresponds to one dimension and can be named. This is probably more useful for multidimensional arrays...

For a `data.frame`, there is no "dimnames" attribute. A `data.frame` is essentially a list, so the list's "names" attributes corresponds to the column names, and an extra "row.names" attribute corresponds to the row names. Because of this, there is no place to store the *names* of the dimnames (they could have an extra attribute for that of course, but they didn't). When you call the `dimnames` function on a data.frame, it simply creates a list from the "row.names" and "names" attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you can't manipulate the dimnames of `x` directly for some reason, and `x` will be coerced to a matrix which isn't preserving named dimnames.

A solution is to coerce to a matrix first, then name the dimnames and then use `apply()`

```
> X <- as.matrix(x)
> str(X)
 num [1:10, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "X1" "X2"
> dimnames(X) <- list(C1 = dimnames(x)[[1]], C2 = dimnames(x)[[2]])
> str(X)
 num [1:10, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ C1: chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ C2: chr [1:2] "X1" "X2"
> apply(X, "C1", mean)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 
> rowMeans(X)
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5
```

Comment: As @Tommy notes, you can't do what you seem to want via this approach, you can only name the dimension over which `FUN` is applied. I posted the Answer as an explanation of what was mean by the named dimnames bit of your Q.