# Optimal Matching/MatchIt Error - argument 'x' must have dimnames

Tags: r

I am attempting to perform optimal matching.

Here is my code:

```
library(MatchIt)
optimalMatching <- matchit(
  Treat ~ Score + Age + Grade + Gender + Subject, 
  distance = dataset1$logitPScores, 
  data = dataset1, 
  method = "optimal", 
  ratio = 1
)
```

Here is the error message:

> Error in fullmatch.matrix(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls =
>   ratio,  :    argument 'x' must have dimnames

What is the cause and how should I troubleshoot it?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R apply error: 'X' must have named dimnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958041/r-apply-error-x-must-have-named-dimnames)

Comment: You may want to reformat the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; check that Treat is numeric or at least that the levels are numbers.